# Regular expression - Extracting strings from a repeating format

Tags: php, regex

**EDIT - SOLVED:**
Thanks for the responses - I learned that this is actually in serialised format and that there's no need to process it using RegEx.

Apologies for the newb question - and I have tried many many variations, based on StackOverflow answers with no luck. I've also spent a while experimenting with an online Regex tool to try and solve this myself.

This is the string I'm checking :

```
i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"3";i:2;s:1:"5";i:3;s:1:"6";
```

I'll settle for matching these strings :

```
i:0;s:1:"1";
i:1;s:1:"3";
i:2;s:1:"5";
i:3;s:1:"6";
```

But ideally I would like to capture *all* the values between quotes only.
(there could be anywhere between 1-10 of these kinds of entries)
i.e. regex_result = [1,3,5,6]

These are some of the regexes I've tried. 
I've only been able to either capture the first match, or the last match, but not all matches - I'm confused as to why the regex isnt "repeating" as I'd expected:

```
(i:.;s:1:".";)*

(i:.;s:1:".";)+

(i:.;s:1:".";)+?
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not using unserialize for that ? (Doc [here](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php))

Comment: Thanks !! I feel a bit retarded now - I've never used PHP serialize/unserialize and didn't know it was in that format. I'm editing an old project someone else did, and I'd thought it was some custom formatting ! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex.

```
/(?<=:")\d+(?=";)/g
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/mF5kJ2/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
"([^"]*)"
```

Try this .See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/43

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`\G`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) so that it would get the number within double quotes which was preceded by `i:.;s:1:"`(*Here the dot after `i:` represents any character*). The anchor \G matches at the position where the previous match ended.

```
<?php
$string = 'i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"3";i:2;s:1:"5";i:3;s:1:"6";';
echo preg_match_all('~(?:i:.;s:1:"|(?<!^)\G)(.)(?=";)~', $string, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
?>
```

Output:

```
4Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 6
)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sK7kB4/4)

Comment: replace `\d+` in the above regex with `[^"]+` if the quotes contain characters other than digits.

Comment: Isn't it overcomplicating the regex ? `i:.;s:1:"(.)";` Should be enought with preg_match_all for the OP need no ?

Comment: @Tensibai it's ok for his example. What if the double quotes contain one or characters? So we leave it to the op.

Comment: We're talking about serialized data here (I'm pretty sure), as long as s:1 is preceding the quoted part, the content of the quoted text  can't be more than 1 char long...

Comment: so it may be any character but length must be one . Am i correct?

Comment: Exactly, in fact OP's string is an array representation, `i:0;` mean integer value 0 `s:1:"1";` mean string 1 char long, litteral value 1, repeat and you have a 0 based array of strings values which is handled by unserialized quite well usually.

Comment: Thanks for the great replies folks. As I belatedly found out, this is actually in a serialised format, so there's no need to process it with RegEx. But thanks for all the great RegEx responses !